# How to pass the "e" parameters to a function called with a trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a simple spreadsheet, and need to do some operations when my form from Google Form is submitted, and the values are inserted in the spreadsheet. Reading the docs I've found that I need triggers, it all seems straightforward, but I am missing something:

```js
function setIncomes(e){
 var sheet = e.source;
 sheet.getRange('a1').setNote(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
 sheet.getRange('a2').setNote(e);
 var row = e.values;

 if(row[4] == "Vincita" || row[4] == "Stipendio"){
   //do nothing
 }else{
  row[2] = 0 - row[2];
 }
 e.range.setValue(row);
 return row;
}
```

The important line is line `4`: `sheet.getRange('a1').setNote(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));`

Here I am getting (for debug sake) the list of the properties of the e object, that, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) should include:

- e.values
- e.range
- e.namedValues

But all I get is:

- e.source
- e.authMode

Why?

I simply defined this function, and link it to a trigger with the apposite menù voice.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `Object`.  Try looping through the object if you want the property names `for (var key in e) {Logger.log('prop name is: ' + key};`

Comment: exactly what trigger are you using, and is it installed on the sheet or on the form?

Comment: I am using the form input trigger, an it is on the sheet @ZigMandel

Comment: what is the name of the trigger?

Comment: It is the `on form submit` and it is `on the spreadsheet`

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e) gives you [namedValues,values,source,range,authMode]. But setNote(e) will give you [object Object]. I am not sure what you are trying to get this script to do?

Comment: @AkshinJalilov I am trying to debug the app writing in a note the output of getOwnPropertyNames, and it works... but I can't understand it gives me `[e.source, e.authMode]` and not the fields the documentation said!

Comment: Where does it give you that? In the notes? I am running the same script and I get what I wrote in the previous comment. Can you post a screenshot? Also try deleting those notes, and submitting another response.

Comment: Yes, it shown in the notes. Here [the screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/jVfeUBt.png?1)

Comment: I am running the same script and getting the correct output. Change sheet.getRange('a2').setNote(e) to sheet.getRange('a2').setNote(e.authMode) just to check if it is an authorisation issue. It should return Full.

Comment: You could also try doing the same thing on a new spreadsheet.

Comment: It gives me exactly `FULL`, I can't really understand why you have the right output!

Comment: Wait, now it seems that I have the right output in A1 cell.... (?????) How is this possibile? Simply changing `e` in `e.authMode`

Comment: It was probably a bug. Just to check, can you change e.authMode back to e to see if it still displays the correct output?

Comment: I've already done it, even in the previous state now the output is right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. I have noticed that is better to delete the trigger, save the script, and re-create it when changes are made to the function that it calls. This way I never had problems, not doing caused strange behaviors.